# How can I properly reset a value associated with a ComboBox, from within a PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I have a `ComboBox` that is bound to a property on my ViewModel (from hear on "VM".)  When a user makes a selection on the `ComboBox` it properly updates the bound property in my VM.  Within my UI code, I have subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event on my VM.

As it should behave, when the user makes a selection within the `ComboBox`, my `PropertyChanged` event is correctly executing in my UI back-end code.  When the UI code catches the change of this property, under certain selection conditions I need to halt the process and request the user for additional information.  From the UI, I send them a dialog.  If they cancel the dialog, I reset the value in the VM that is associated with the `ComboBox` controls `SelectedValue`.

This is what I've observed.  When the operation is cancelled by the user, my VM property is being set to the new value.  However, the `ComboBox` is still showing the text value of the original entry that has now changed.  How can I force the `ComboBox` to update itself from within my `PropertyChanged` event?  In this case, I think it's just a textual issue or numeric index change that's referencing the text data from the bound collection.  The data is correct in the VM but the display value for the `ComboBox` is wrong.

**EXAMPLE**

**ComboBox Details**

```
    <ComboBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectionIsAnEnumeration}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Text"
        SelectedValuePath="EnumerationValue"
        Height="27" />
```

Sorry for the wordy properties on the VM, but that's to explain what's happening.  My `ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects` collection represents a set of enumerator values that are stored in the path within `SelectedValuePath`.  The descriptive text for each value is pulled from the `ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects` which is a special list strictly created for the UI. This basically pairs an enumeration value with a meaningful description.

**ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects Definition (from within VM)**

*Edit #1 - Added this definition to my example*

```
 private ObservableCollection<BindableEnumerationItem<Values>> _listOfComboBoxDisplayObjects;
public ObservableCollection<BindableEnumerationItem<Values>> ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects
{
    get { return _listOfComboBoxDisplayObjects; }
    private set
    {
        if (value != _listOfComboBoxDisplayObjects)
        {
            _listOfComboBoxDisplayObjects= value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects)));
        }
    }
}
```

**MySelectionIsAnEnumeration Definition (From within VM)**

*Edit #1: Adding this code definition.

```
    private Values_mySelectionIsAnEnumeration ;
    public Values MySelectionIsAnEnumeration 
    {
        get { return _mySelectionIsAnEnumeration; }
        set
        {
            //Double-checked this-- value is different on the second-call to change this value, once the UI cancels the operation.
            if (value != _mySelectionIsAnEnumeration)
            {
                _mySelectionIsAnEnumeration= value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MySelectionIsAnEnumeration )));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Pertinent Values Associated with ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects**

*These values are generated in the ctor of the VM.  They are fixed throughout the application.*

Item #1

- Text: "This is a Foo!"
- Value: Values.Foo

Item #2:

- Text: "Hi, I'm Bar."
- Value: Values.Bar

Item #3:

- Text: "This is Baz. I need to ask a question before I can be used."
- Value: Values.Baz

**PropertyChanged Event - From the UI Back-End**

```
private void VM_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "MySelectionIsAnEnumeration":
                    if (VM.MySelectionIsAnEnumeration == Values.Baz)
                    {
                        //Prompt the user and get DialogResult.
                        bool answerGiven = AskAQuestionAndGetAResult();
                        if(!answerGiven)
                            VM.MySelectionIsAnEnumeration = Values.Foo;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

After executing the above code, what I'm observing is that the `VM.MySelectionIsAnEnumeration` value is indeed changing to the proper value of `Value.Foo` when a user cancels the operation within `AskAQuestionAndGetAResult()`.  However, after it's finished the `ComboBox` still reads *"This is Baz. I need to ask a question before I can be used."*, which is obviously the display value associated with `Value.Baz`.

How can I update both the underlying VM property AND the display text on the `CombobBox` to correctly show the valued that is now stored in `VM.MySelectionIsAnEnumeration`?

**Edit #2**

Below is the code efor my `BindableEnumerationItem` that I use within my Observable Collections for comboxes and list boxes.  This is used throughout my application in simpler cases and has caused no issue.  Please note, this is my actual, unaltered code.  I've not renamed anything.  My comboboxes can bind to each `Item` property for a type-safe property and `DisplayText` is the descriptor text.

```
public class BindableEnumerationItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private T _item;

    public BindableEnumerationItem(T item, string displayText)
    {
        _item = item;
        _displayText = displayText;
    }

    private string _displayText;
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return _displayText; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _displayText)
            {
                _displayText = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayText"));
            }
        }
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set
        {
            _item = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If view doesn't update binding, then somewhere is missing notification or a binding error. Can you show `ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects`, its type and `MySelectionIsAnEnumeration`?

Comment: @Sinatr, the values within `ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects` are the values provided in the section **Pertinent Values Associated with ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects**.  In this case, the enumerator type is `Values`.  These are arbitrary values that I've created to simplify the example.  Regarding binding, all binding operations appear to be functioning properly.  Usually when there is a problem with binding, the debugger will output the issue to the Debug output window.  In this case, I'm seeing no messages or errors after the re-assignment.

Comment: To be clear, binding is properly working and has been double-checked, when a users selects `Foo` or `Bar`.  Even `Baz` is properly working when a user appropriately responds to the prompts.  However, when the operation is cancelled, the UI element within the ComboBox is not updating the text but I am certain the underlying value in my VM is correct.

Comment: I am not asking for values, but a source code of that property, its type, etc. If you sure that the issue is more than a missing notification, then it's well worth to try prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You describe very well problem input and output, but didn't show all critical parts where you could (theoretically) make a mistake.

Comment: @Sinatr, I'll add that to the question.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I think you should not be writing domain logic in the view model property changed handlers, but instead wire up a attached property that wires a command from the viewmodel to the Selector's SelectionChanged event. So then you can have a much cleaner way to do this from within the viewmodel and not intervene with the property update process.

Comment: @Sinatr.  Updated the code.

Comment: What is `BindableEnumerationItem` and `Values` ? Seems you forgot to override `Equals` for `Values`, expected behavior to compare values right? Without - it will compare references, so setting `ComboBox.SelectedValue` to something what is not reference in `ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects` will obviously won't change current selection of `ComboBox` (as it can't find item). Override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode` ofc) of `Values`.

Comment: `Values` can be explicitly defined above, if needed, but it is a an enumeration.  So it's defined like `public enum Values {Foo, Bar, Baz}`.  No override needed since it is a value type. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Sinatr See *Edit #2* for the definition of my `BindableEnumerationItem` class.

Comment: Shouldn't the values of `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` in your `Binding` match the property names in `BindableEnumerationItem`?

Comment: @wkl, yes, and they do.  I had simplified my actual code in my original post, and I changed the names so that they would be a bit more descriptive.  However, on a second edit, I copy-and-pasted my `BindableEnumerationItem` directly from my code, to the question.  I was in a bit of a rush and I didn't update the names.  Suffice to say, the names are proper in my actual code.  This has been triple-checked and is verifiable because selected values are, in fact, the proper enumeration values and the proper text is also being displayed for each ComboBox entry.

Comment: Have you tried (not as a solution but for testing) to programmatically change the value of `VM.MySelectionIsAnEnumeration` in a different place in your code (so that it is decoupled of the `PropertyChanged` handler) and see if your ComboBox is updated properly then? I wonder if it only goes wrong when done in the event handler or if this direction of the binding does not work at all. (Maybe due to the missing `Equals` as Sinatr mentioned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an extension that will wire up the command from your viewmodel in xaml to the selector, which in this case is the combobox.

```
public partial class Extensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectionChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Extensions), new UIPropertyMetadata((s, e) =>
    {
        var element = s as Selector;

        if (element != null)
        {
            element.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;

            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                element.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }));

    public static ICommand GetSelectionChangedCommand(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ICommand)element.GetValue(SelectionChangedCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectionChangedCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SelectionChangedCommandProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as Selector;
        var command = element.GetValue(SelectionChangedCommandProperty) as ICommand;

        if (command != null && command.CanExecute(element.SelectedItem))
        {
            command.Execute(element.SelectedItem);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Create the command in the viewmodel that handles the value changed event.

```
public ICommand EnumerationValueChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(
            () =>
                {
                    if (VM.MySelectionIsAnEnumeration == Values.Baz)
                    {
                        //Prompt the user and get DialogResult.
                        bool answerGiven = AskAQuestionAndGetAResult();
                        if (!answerGiven)
                            VM.MySelectionIsAnEnumeration = Values.Foo;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

And then bind using that extension. ext is the namespace for your extensions.

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfComboBoxDisplayObjects}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectionIsAnEnumeration}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    SelectedValuePath="EnumerationValue"
    ext:Extensions.SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding EnumerationValueChangedCommand}"
    Height="27" />
```

Comment: I do like this approach, but I'd like to check it's source.  Where did this code come from, or what code base was it modified from?

Comment: Sorry, one more question.  The command needs to launch a prompt window.  Has does it fire the prompt from the UI?

Comment: It is something I wrote for selectors when I got tired that combobox does not provide the command wireability out of the box and in MVVM all your logic should be in the viewmodel. When the command is executed, it will be executed in the ui thread, so your dialog should be modal dialog preferably, because you do want to interrupt the user.